# ImageMagick Convert Loop Hangs

Tags: linux, bash

I am running a script intended to resize all images in a folder and its subdirectories if the dimensions are of a certain size. The script hangs on the "convert" line after getting through about 1,000-2,000 images. (The exact image it hangs on is different every time).

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in $(find . -wholename "./raw/*.jpg"); do
    # fwidth, fheight, outputdir, filename variables defined...

    if [ "$fwidth" -gt 1000 ] || [ "$fheight" -gt 1000 ]; then
        convert -resize 60% -quality 92 -unsharp 0x0.5 $f ${outputdir}/${filename};
    else
        cp $f ${outputdir}/${filename};
    fi
done
```

Comment: Should find have a `-type f` specifier to only find files, not sure what convert will do on any directories?

Comment: It has managed to go through multiple directories so I think it is working okay as is.

Comment: Hit the same problem. Did you get a fix?

Comment: in my case a newly installed ImageMagick took ages to convert the first image, but after that they were all pretty fast. I wondered if it was some kind of JIT compilation but I think IM is written in C++ so not sure

Answer (score 1):

First of describe in more detail what "hanging" means. Does it stop execution? Does `convert` work at 100% CPU usage for some time? Something else?

Then start debugging the script. Please add some debugging output and try to run the script with `bash -x script.sh` which should output all commands actually ran.

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in $(find . -wholename "./raw/*.jpg"); do
    echo "=========== processing file $f"
    # fwidth, fheight, outputdir, filename variables defined...

    if [ "$fwidth" -gt 1000 ] || [ "$fheight" -gt 1000 ]; then
        convert -verbose -resize 60% -quality 92 -unsharp 0x0.5 $f ${outputdir}/${filename};
    else
        cp -v $f ${outputdir}/${filename};
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. The CPU usage stays at about 60% when it hangs (it is around 30% when the script is not running). What I mean by hanging is that `bash -x script` will get stuck on `convert -resize...` during one of the iterations for over an hour (and then I kill the script). It is not always the same file that it happens to. Also, there are no special characters in the filenames.

Comment: If you execute the command that never succeeded on the command line later on, does it work?

Comment: Good question. `convert -resize 60% -quality 92 -unsharp 0x0.5 ./raw/data/2/default_2_fk.jpg ./edited/data/2/default_2_fk.jpg` was the line that the script last hung on and it also hung when I ran it from the command line. As far as I can tell there is nothing special about this image. And it worked on the command line when I changed the destination folder, even though the script was able to save other images to that destination folder.

Comment: I ran the script a few more times. It turns out that it tends to get stuck one of about 3 different images. I'm not sure what is special about them.

Comment: It looks like the bash script is fully okay but `convert` is having problems with your special files.

Comment: @halo & user: Add double quotes: `"$f"` to catch spaces and other odd characters. Any filenames that begin with a hyphen might also cause strange behaviours.

Comment: You're right Dave I'll do that. I'm guessing I should also do that for `${outputdir}/${filename}`.

Comment: Did this fix the hanging? I'm having a similar issue, livelock on all files.